# How to use two different date formats: yymmdd and dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: formatting, datetime, date, datetime2

I would like to be able to use, in the same document, these two date formats:

- dd/mm/yyyy (as default format)
- yymmdd (as "local" format)

### Why I want that?

Because I would like to use the "local" format to define the document reference code (e.g. `mydocumenttitle_yymmdd.pdf`) but in "normal" text, I would like to use the default `dd/mm/yyyy` format with the command `\today`.

### First attempt

For the moment I wasn't able to do better than this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdate{specialdate}{\day}{\month}{\year}
\usepackage[datesep={}]{datetime2} 

\begin{document}
Format with dd/mm/yyyy: {\ddmmyyyydate\displaydate{specialdate}}

Format with yymmdd: \today
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

But there are the following problems:

1. The `yymmdd` format is not correct because I achieve only `yyyymmdd`. **How to obtain the date format with only two digits for the year: `yymmdd`?**
2. The use of command `\today` doens't give the default format but the `yymmdd` one.
   **Is there a way to define `\today` with the default format (i.e. `dd/mm/yyyy`) and another command for the "local" format (i.e. `yymmdd`)?**
3. It use the two packages `datetime` and `datetime2`.
   **Is it possible to use only one package?**

Comment: (I don't get why people want to use more/less packages. Does copying the source code of the package into the document count?)

Comment: Also, you most likely don't want to redefine LaTeX commands (such as `\today`), it may mess up some packages.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for your comment about `\today`. About your fisrt comment, imho, limiting the number of packages helps prevent future package incompatibilities. When working on large documents with lots of packages it can also make a major difference in terms of readability. But here my concern was not to limit the number of packages but I thought that if there was a `datetime2` it was perhaps to replace the `datetime` package... I should have specified that in my question sorry.

Comment: Hm reading the documentation it looks like that datetime2 is indeed intended to replace datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: b]

The package `datetime` is obsolete. Only `datetime2` is needed.

Two styles have been defined to present the desired date formats --default (`ddmmyyyyx`) and local (`yymmdd`)--.

Using `\DTMsetstyle{<name>}` in the preamble sets the default style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}  

    
\DTMnewstyle{yymmdd}{%
\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{%
\DTMtwodigits{##1}\DTMtwodigits{##2}\DTMtwodigits{##3}% 
}
\renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
{}{}{}

\newcommand{\daymonthyearsep}{/}    % define the separator
\DTMnewstyle{ddmmyyyyx}{%
\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{%
\DTMtwodigits{##3}\daymonthyearsep\DTMtwodigits{##2}\daymonthyearsep\number##1%
}%
\renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
{}{}{}  


\DTMsetstyle{ddmmyyyyx}% set as default style

\begin{document}

Default style \emph{ddmmyyyyx}: \today
\bigskip

Now a local style \emph{yymmdd}: {\DTMsetstyle{yymmdd} \today}%local style <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\bigskip

Default style again \emph{ddmmyyyyx}:   \today
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks a lot!